# How to read raspberry's pin using node.js?

Tags: raspbian, node.js, wiringpi

I know how to write to a pin but I can't find an example of how to read for example 3.3v from a input pin using node.js.

I use wiring-pi to write, how would you do it with an example?

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/wiring-pi.

```
var wpi = require('wiring-pi');
wpi.setup('wpi');

var pin = 0;

wpi.pinMode(pin, wpi.OUTPUT);

var value = 1;

setInterval(function() {
  wpi.digitalWrite(pin, value);
  value = +!value;
}, 500);
```

That works for me. What I want to do now is to read from a pin and launch an event. I can't find any example of it.

Comment: Show what you've tried already, so we can figure out where you're going wrong.

Comment: What npm package you used for providing the access of GPIO functionalities? When you say you know how to write a pin, what is your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its all in the official documentation for the API you are using: https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi-Node/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION.md#core

From the docs:

> digitalRead(pin)
>
> `>= 0.1.1`
>
> This function returns the value read at the given pin.
>
> It will be HIGH (1) or LOW (0) depending on the logic level at the pin.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after some search around I found a way:

```
  var c = 0;
  var status;

  function globalIntervalChecker() 
  { 
    if (c===5){
      status = wpi.digitalRead(pin);
      c = 0;      
    }
  }

  globalInterval = setInterval(globalIntervalChecker, 1000);
```